# Always raising "Gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction" when the condition of require() is not met

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, require

I tried to run the following code to check the error message when the condition of `require()` is not met.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
...
function addUser(string memory name) public returns (int) {
   require(!userList[msg.sender].isSigned, "You already have an account.");
   ...
}
```

When the condition of `require()` is met, it worked as expected, but when the condition wasn't met, I could always see the following error message:

> transact to Messenger.addUser errored: gas required exceeds allowance (8946128) or always failing transaction

I thought that the problem was due to the gas limit of the block, so I increased the gas limit from ten thousand to one million. However, the problem was not solved and I don't know what the cause is.

What I want to ask is

- Does solidity always show that error message when the condition of `require()` is not met?
- How to check the message("You already have an account.") I specified in `require()`?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: "How to check the message("You already have an account.") I specified in `require()`?" - what does that mean?

Comment: I thought the second parameter of require() would be the error message, and it would be printed when the condition of require () was not met. Is it right?
I want to see that message printed out. (In my case, "You already have an account.")

Comment: It is right actually. At least that's the case in Truffle 4.x, which relies on Web3 0.x (so I'm not sure which one of those two is in charge of this feature). Your error-message is from Web3 v1.x as far as I'm aware of; not really sure how you could get your require-message on that one.

Answer (score 1):

> Does solidity always show that error message when the condition of `require` is not met?

First of all, it is not Solidity which generates this error-message, it is Web3.js.

Second, it is indeed arguably not the most suitable error-message because it makes one think that it has something to do with the gas, where in fact the transaction reverts because the condition of the `require` is not met. But if you take a good look at that message, then you'll see "**or** always failing transaction", which aligns perfectly with the reason of the failure.

Comment: I'd previously run the smart contract using Web3 Provider in remix. But using Javascript VM, I could see the message I set. Your advice was helpful. Thank you :)